# Binary subtraction with borrow

Tags: binary

$1000_2 - 0111_2$ = $8_{10}-7_{10} = 1_{10}$.

When there are no more on-bits to borrow from the number that is being subtracted from, is the resultings bits in the sum all zeros? (Se pic)

[image]

We know the result is $1$. So when there are no bits to borrow is the result zero?

Comment: Don't understand what the question is exactly. Does your example illustrate your question?

Comment: You borrow from the digit on the left? Binary subtraction works similar to decimal subtraction. How do you subtract $111_{10}$ from $1000_{10}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from the question,

$$\begin{array}{rrrrr}
&1&0&0&0\\
-&&1&1&1\\
\hline
\end{array}$$

From the rightmost digit, it needs to borrow from the left, so column-wise,

$$\begin{array}{rrrrr}
&1&0&0&0\\
&&&\tiny{-1}&\tiny{+10}\\
-&&1&1&1\\
\hline\\
\end{array}
\longrightarrow
\begin{array}{rrrrr}
&1&0&0&0\\
&&&\tiny{-1}&\tiny{+10}\\
-&&1&1&1\\
\hline
&&&&1
\end{array}$$

Then the twos-digit, it also needs to borrow enough from the left to subtract 1 twice,

$$\begin{array}{rrrrr}
&1&0&0&0\\
&&&\tiny{-1}&\tiny{+10}\\
&&\tiny{-1}&\tiny{+10}\\
-&&1&1&1\\
\hline
&&&&1
\end{array}
\longrightarrow
\begin{array}{rrrrr}
&1&0&0&0\\
&&&\tiny{-1}&\tiny{+10}\\
&&\tiny{-1}&\tiny{+10}\\
-&&1&1&1\\
\hline
&&&0&1
\end{array}$$

Then the fours-digit and up,

$$\begin{array}{rrrrr}
&1&0&0&0\\
&&&\tiny{-1}&\tiny{+10}\\
&&\tiny{-1}&\tiny{+10}\\
&\tiny{-1}&\tiny{+10}\\
-&&1&1&1\\
\hline
&&&0&1
\end{array}
\longrightarrow
\begin{array}{rrrrr}
&1&0&0&0\\
&&&\tiny{-1}&\tiny{+10}\\
&&\tiny{-1}&\tiny{+10}\\
&\tiny{-1}&\tiny{+10}\\
-&&1&1&1\\
\hline
&0&0&0&1
\end{array}$$

So $$1000-111=1$$